# How to replace some of text, by other some of text

Tags: macros, xetex, strings

I want to replace some of text, by other some of text! See my example:

```
\begin{document}
  This (1) is (2).

  (1: book)
  (2: good)
\end{document}
```

I want to see this output in PDF:

```
«This book is good.»
```

Can I do it in LaTeX? How can I do it? I must use XeLaTeX.

Comment: why do you not want to use tex markup for this? (it is what tex was designed to do)

Comment: The markup is *extra* confusing, since you use parens as both the label and the reference.

Comment: Are you okay with changing your markup to use a more TeX-y syntax?

Comment: I want to use only my custom format. I mean like my example in my question.

Comment: Are you willing to give up on using parentheses for the rest of your document?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you consider the following code:

```
\documenclass{article}
\newcommand\subA{book}
\newcommand\subB{good}

\begin{document}
This \subA{} is \subB.
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, I want to use only my custom format. I mean like my example in my question.

Comment: @AliHardan - What's wrong with using TeX-based tools in a TeX document?

Answer (score 3):

After a fashion...

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mylabel(#1: #2){\expandafter\def\csname MY#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\myref(#1){\csname MY#1\endcsname}
\begin{document}
  \mylabel(1: book)
  \mylabel(2: good)

This \myref(1) is \myref(2).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a custom command.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\newcommand{\replace}[2]{This #1 is #2.}
\begin{document}
\replace{book}{good}

\replace{novel}{great}
\end{document}
```